# How to define limits to camera movement

Tags: aframe

I have a panorama image binded to a `<a-sky>`, i want to limite how much to the left/right and up/down the user can move the camera:
I have disabled WASD movement with `<a-camera wasd-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>` but i found no similar controls for camera view movement. Is it possible only with script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A-Frame does not have this behavior built in. The framework prioritizes VR and AR experiences (where you cannot practically control where someone will look) so you would need to make a custom version of [look-controls.js](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/look-controls.js) to do what you describe.